# Show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a rational number $p$, such that $|p-\sqrt[3]{2}|<\varepsilon$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am new to abstract algebra and find difficult to prove things like these.

> > Show that for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a rational number $p$, such that $|p-\sqrt[3]{2}|<\varepsilon$.

Yes this is a homework question, so I am just looking for hints.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried so far? Also, have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve your mathematical expressions.

Comment: @AlainRemillard Thanks! I will take care of that in my future posts

Comment: @DeepBodra To show your code in mathjax, you need to write it between \$ signs, like \$x^2$.

Comment: I am sure I am wrong. It kind of seems circular to me. Is this a correct proof? Case 1: $p>\sqrt[3]{2}$ This gives $p<\sqrt[3]{2}+\epsilon$. There is a rational number which satisfies both $p>\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $p<\sqrt[3]{2}+\epsilon$. Reason: There is a rational number between any two real numbers. Similarly for case 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** For given integer $m$, can you show that there exists an integer $n$ that differs from $m\sqrt[3]2$  by less than $1$?

Comment: Is this equivalent to the given statement because $|\frac{p}{\varepsilon}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{\varepsilon}|<1$ ? obtained by replacing $p$ by $\frac{n}{m}$ where $n,m$ are integers?

Comment: How did you get rid of ε?

Answer (score 1):

HiNT: take the decimal expansion of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and truncate it properly.